# Security credentials tab not present for the user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am just starting out with AWS. I have a root user and an IAM user. I'm trying to create an access key for my IAM user, but I can't find the security credentials tab as listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html).

[image]

[image]

As you see in the second screenshot, the Security Credentials tab is missing. I can access the security credentials for the root user by clicking on the username in the upper right hand corner, but the same method does not work when I log in to my IAM user account. Any ideas on how to get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There used to be a service called **AWS Single Sign-On (SSO)**. This has recently been renamed as **IAM Identity Center**.

This is *different* to **Identity and Access Management (IAM)**. ([Link](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home))

Therefore, you are **using the wrong management console**.

It's not your fault... it's due to AWS giving different services the same name.

Comment: Thanks John. I went to the link that you tagged but that shows no users. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: Have you created any users in the AWS Account? The user you created in the **IAM Identity Center** is _not_ an IAM User. You should delete them from there and create them in the **IAM** console.

Comment: Ahh okay. Guess I'll have to look into it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As previously stated, IAM Identity Center and IAM are different services for different use-cases.

When using AWS Organizations with multiple accounts, you could use IAM Identity Center (previously AWS Single Sign-On) to manage your users in a centralized way. Users have SSO access to your accounts and can create temporary programmatic keys (access key and secret key).

When using single account you use IAM, which allows you to create users that can have programmatic keys, console access, Git credentials, SSH keys, and certificates.